# Magento - How to add Layered Navigation to Advanced Search?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I add Layered Navigation to the Advanced Search result pages?

Magento Version 1.7.

Comment: You can check this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248461/magento-layered-navigation-on-advanced-search-results/15128386#15128386

Answer (score 8):

The patch below will display the layered navigation in Advanced search result and will work fine with layered navigations. 
The layered navigation and search result are displayed based on two separate product collections, one created by **catalogsearch/Model/Layer.php** and the other by **catalogsearch/Model/Advanced.php**.
So we need to override few functions of both these models to make layered nav work in Advanced search.

1- In your local.xml under **catalogsearch_advanced_result** tag add.

```
 <reference name="left">
      <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

**Override prepareProductCollection function of catalogsearch/model/Layer.php** with

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection){

    if(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())//for normal search we get the value from query string q=searchtext
        return parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);
    else{

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
        /**
         * make sure you cross check the $_REQUEST with $attributes
         */
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributes();

        Mage::log(print_r($_REQUEST,1));
        foreach($attributes as $attribute){
            $attribute_code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            //Mage::log("--->>". $attribute_code);
            if($attribute_code == "price")//since i am not using price attribute
                continue;

            if (empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code])){
                //Mage::log("nothing found--> $attribute_code");
                continue;
            }
            if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]) && is_array($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('in' => $_REQUEST[$attribute_code]));
            else
            if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('like' => "%" . $_REQUEST[$attribute_code] . "%"));
        }

        $collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addUrlRewrite();

        //Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());

        Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->prepareProductCollection($collection);    
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Override getProductCollection, getSearchCriterias function of catalogsearch/model/Advanced.php** with

```
public function getProductCollection(){

    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);

        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) 
            $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']),true);
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}

public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $search = parent::getSearchCriterias();
    /* display category filtering criteria */
    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']);
        $search[] = array('name'=>'Category','value'=>$category->getName());
    }
    return $search;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no quick solution for this. The standard search and the advanced search use two different methods to search.

If you compare the layouts in `catalogsearch.xml` you see that for `catalogsearch_advanced_result` the block `catalogsearch/layer` is not included. If you copy the block definition from `catalogsearch_result_index` and change the root template to `3columns.phtml` various errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In my 1.6.2 the layered nav showed up after setting a 0 (Zero) to 
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Apply Layered Navigation if Search Results are Less Than

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/layered-navigation) goes to Magento website should help. You need to create attributes from Catalogues. Then see the settings under Frontend Properties (Catalogues>Attributes).

Comment: Thanks for your link, although it is not what I'm looking for. The link describes how to add Layered Navigation to the website (which I know how to do). My question is about adding the Layered Navigation to **Advanced Search** specifically (which seems to ignore the generic settings).

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding following line in `catalogsearch.xml` advance search results **left** area helped me to get it visible on my EE site, however I haven't checked it in CE version.

```
<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

So my full left area looks like this on advance search area on xml file:

```
<reference name="left">
       <block type="catalog/navigation" name="hello.leftnav" as="hello.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/hello_left_nav-search.phtml" />
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Hope it helps others.