# Magento Active Filters on Search Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to implement active filters on my magento ecommerce site.

I have been successful in implementing it, but the issue is, the code works on only category pages and not search page

Here's the code that I'm using

```
<?php /*Create filter dependencies*/

$_activeFilters[] = array();

$_filters = Mage::getSingleton(‘Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State’)->getActiveFilters();

foreach ($_filters as $_filter):?>
<?php echo $this->stripTags($_filter->getLabel()) ?><a href=”<?php echo $_filter-     >getRemoveUrl() ?>” title=”<?php echo $this->__(‘Remove This Item’) ?>”><?php echo $this->__(‘Remove This Item’) ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm using this code in toolbar.phtml. Any clue as in why its not working on search page. Any  Solutions would be of great help.

Thanks,

Sushil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code for fetching filters on either category list page or search results page

```
   <?php
   if(Mage::registry('current_category')) {
       $_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
   } else {
       $_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
   }
   ?>
```

I have used this code in toolbar.phtml, to show removable filters below the toolbar, like flipkart does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
$_filters = Mage::getSingleton(‘Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State’)->getActiveFilters();
```

This gets a singleton which only contains the necessary data when on a category page.

See this question for more details: [Magento - How to add Layered Navigation to Advanced Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503447/magento-how-to-add-layered-navigation-to-advanced-search)

Comment: So there's no way of getting this on catalog search page?

Comment: There probably is, but you would need some extensive coding, and expertise with magento