# How do I add layered navigation in the advanced search results in Magento?

Tags: magento, search, advanced-search

I want to display layered navigation in Magento’s advanced search results.

Comment: what kind of navigation you want to add?

Comment: Magento Default layered navigation which is display on search result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503447/magento-how-to-add-layered-navigation-to-advanced-search

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that Magento uses a completely different search backend for advanced search this is not possible as standard.