# How to show layered navigation on Advanced search result in Magento

Tags: magento, search, navigation, layered

I would like to add layered navigation block on Advanced Search Result(catalogsearch/advanced/result/) either on Right or left column. Though, I have added below code in my catalogsearch.xml under catalogsearch_advanced_result but layered navigation not showing.

`<reference name="left">
<!--  <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>-->
                     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>`

If you see the first commented block(catalogsearch/layer) it throws an error and so I have putted second block(catalog/layer_view) it throws no error, but layered navigation also not displaying.

Comment: Have you tried it with catalogsearch_result_index ?

Comment: Yes, on  catalogsearch_result_index this block is showing.But I want layered navigation to be displayed on catalogsearch_advanced_result section

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503447/magento-how-to-add-layered-navigation-to-advanced-search

Comment: Thanks for the link Dushyant. but still answer is missing :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following extension. It works good out of the box. Very nice and compatible to 1.4+ magento versions.

http://www.xthemers.com/xt-advanced-layered-navigation.html